# TYPO3 9.5.x URL Segment (slug) ignore page

Tags: typo3, slug, typo3-9.x

In the past we organized pages inside the page-tree by putting them into pages like "meta" or "submenu". These pages had the option "exclude from speaking url" so their name was not rendered to the url.

Is there any option to do this in TYPO3 9.5 to ignore pages from generating the "slug"?

as example:

WRONG: https: //www.somedomain.tld/metamenu/terms-and-conditions/

RIGHT: https: //www.somedomain. tld/terms-and-conditions/

How to "ignore" the page "metamenu" for automatic-generating the slug?

Best regards
Johannes

Answer (score 2):

It is mandatory for a page to have set a slug and every menulevel will generate another url part. It is not possible to exclude a page - think about how to access this page via url

Here Mathias Schreiber tells a bit about this feature: [Feature Demo - Speaking URLs Part 1](https://youtu.be/dUz4B08XFes?t=70)

Comment: Hello. Sometimes we use "shortcuts" to structure the page-tree and putting resources for its sub-tree in it. In this case the page does not need to be accessible by url - it's just an element for structuring/organizing the page-tree.

Comment: @JohannesC.Schulz Well, while I having the same problem I think the right way to structure the page tree are folders. They are excluded automatically and can contain the setup you need.

Answer (score 2):

The [TYPO3 extension "masi"](https://github.com/b13/masi) provides this feature, including an upgrade wizard that migrates the realurl `tx_realurl_exclude` settings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Folder instead of a "Page"?

page/page/page
somedomain.tld/metamenu/terms-and-conditions/

page/folder/page
somedomain.tld/terms-and-conditions/

Comment: Thankx. This works for a simple example in case we do not need the page to be a shortcut (or page). Often we use the "organizers" configured as shortcut to redirect to first subpage.  This isn't possible if the "organizer" is a folder.

Comment: ah, ok :) well you can edit the slug itself and remove unwanted parts, but thats not really as convienient as realurl was :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the parent-page as it is and edit your child-pages. There you can delete parts of the urls in the slug-field.

Comment: Its not about manualy editing the slug, its about an automatism/configuration. Think about hundreds of subpages - I don't want to edit them all by hand.

Answer (score 0):

There's a feature in RealURL for TYPO3 8.7 "Exclude from speaking URL". If set 'domain.com/page-one/' loads 'page-one' and 'domain.com/subpage-of-page-one/' loads 'subpage-of-page-one' with no need of 'page-one' in the URL.

The very same thing can be achieved in TYPO3 9.5 manually editing slugs but you can't set the parent page to be excluded from the URL automatically.
It's a missing feature.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem. Sadly there is no "good" solution as far as i know. But there is a little trick. You can fix this in the database. I deleted all my "slug"-entries in in the database for my pages. Then i wrote in all pages wich should not show in the url in slug "/". This does sadly not work in TYPO3, because the BE allows just one "/" and the second "/" will be changed to "/1". But in the Database you can do it. After you edited the slug for your page metamenu and other to "/", you can go into the upgrade-wizard in the installtools, reset the "generate slugs" task and run this task again. This is sadly the only solution i came up with.